# How to transliterate text from English to Arabic using java script, j query or angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

while entering text in text box , in change it should should show the converted text in another text box.

```js
function OnLoad() {                
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
        google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
        [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ARABIC],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    control.makeTransliteratable(["txtArabic"]);
    var keyVal = 32; // Space key
    $("#txtEnglish").on('keydown', function(event)  {
        //console.log("keyVal",keyVal);
        //console.log("event.keyCode",event.keyCode);
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
            var engText = $("#txtEnglish").val() + " ";
            var engTextArray = engText.split(" ");
            $("#txtArabic").val(engTextArray[engTextArray.length-2]);

            document.getElementById("txtArabic").focus();
            $("#txtArabic").trigger ( {
                type: 'keypress', keyCode: keyVal, which: keyVal, charCode: keyVal
            } );
        }
    });
    $("#txtEnglish").on('change', function(event)  {
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    console.log("test");
 });

} //end onLoad function

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

Comment: please give some suggestions?

Comment: You could [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) each a-zA-Z with some arabic letter (but I'm not familiar with arabic alphabet - do you have the same number of characters?)

Comment: it should work like google translate. i can't use replace for each word or text because user can enter anything.

Comment: There's a difference between translation and transliteration. Use some translation API.

Comment: yes. we have to use transliteration.For that we have any free API?